# Loading images asynchronously in windows 8 metro apps

Tags: windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 app development. In my app I need to display a `GridView` with images and title. The image URL and the title I get from the server as a XML data. The images are downloaded from the given URL and stored in a local directory. Now, when an image is downloaded I want to notify the `GridView` and update the particular image view with the downloaded image. I store the title and the local image URI in an `ObservableCollection`. The data source of the `GridView` is bound to this `ObservableCollection`, so once the XML data is downloaded I am able to update the title through the ObservableCollection. But i don't know how to update the images once they are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your image is saved in the local data folder (`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`) - you can create a new `BitmapImage` this way:

```
var imagePathInLocalDataFolder = ?
var imageUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + imagePathInLocalDataFolder, UriKind.Absolute);
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUri));
```

You can then assign the `bitmapImage` variable value to a property that you bind to an `Image.Source` - and you should see your image.

Comment: i have attacthed the source property of my imageview to the local uri.Once the image is downloaded and stored into the local folder,the local uri is updated.But the update is not reflected in the gridview.

Comment: I was able to update the gridview by reseting the gridview ie maingridview.winControl.itemDataSource = null;
maingridview.winControl.itemDataSource = dataSource;